# Ignore change API during insert

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb

I have change API implementation in a node application for a single table. So, for any change(insert, update and delete) change notification will fire to node driver.

What I like to do is disable change for certain inserts(based on some business condition). So during insert to the table, if my business condition satisfied than I dont want rethinkdb to fire change notification to node driver.

Is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a `.filter` before the call to `.changes` (or afterward if you want to exclude changes based on the old_val/new_val pair).